# How do I convert String array into Json Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array like string[] sentences which consist of sentences one in each index like `This is the first message` in `sentences[0]` and `This is the second message` in `sentences[1]` and so on. My java code to send the information to the server for sentiment analysis is like this:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());  
        out.write(
                "[ " +
                "\"Can't wait for the movie\"," +
                "\"Countdown! Only ten days remaining!\" " +
                "]");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

How do I replace the texts above in the code by the string array for it's length say n?

Comment: _How do I add an array of string into the following JSON?_, where is the JSON? this question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Got it, sorry. Anyway, how do I convert this array of string into JSON array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) library, which convert **Java object** to **Json String**

```
    String[] sentences=new String[3];
    sentences[0]="Hi";
    sentences[1]="Hello";
    sentences[2]="How r u?";

    Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().create();
    String jsonArray=gson.toJson(sentences);

    //["Hi","Hello","How r u?"]

    out.write(jsonArray);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Comment: Hey, I tried that but then I got 200: bad JSON format error as the response. I tried this but I'm not sure whether it's right. It responds with neutral to all.
 `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()); 
out.write( "[ " + "\"+tweets[0]+\"," + "\"+tweets[1]+\" " + "]"); 
out.flush(); 
out.close();` What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is a loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sb.append(array[i]);
    if(i < array.length-1) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
}
out.write(sb.append("]").toString());
```

**But this has the problem of producing potentially invalid JSON (unescaped)**. Hence:

The best solution, however, would be to use a proper JSON/Java binding library such as Jackson, Gson, etc.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but then I got 200: bad JSON format error as the response. I tried this but I'm not sure whether it's right. It responds with neutral to all. `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());  
    out.write(
            "[ " +
            "\"+tweets[0]+\"," +
            "\"+tweets[1]+\" " +
            "]");
    out.flush();
    out.close();`   What could be the issue?

Comment: As I pointed out, this can produce invalid json. That's why you're highly encouraged to use Jackson or Gson.

Comment: `StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("[ \"");
   for(int x=0;x<val;x++)
   {
    String a=xyz[x].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ");
    sb.append("+");
    sb.append(a);
    if(x < val-1) 
    {
     sb.append("+\",\"");
    }
   }
    sb.append("+\" ]");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    out.write(sb.toString());` 
This worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!